# Clear Magento Enterprise FPC for specific product

Tags: cache, full-page-cache

We want to clear the full page cache for a specific product - based on the ID of the product (or the URL if needs be). I have found this line:

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache('catalog_product_'.$this->getId());
```

In app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php:

```
public function cleanCache()
{
    Mage::app()->cleanCache('catalog_product_'.$this->getId());
    return $this;
}
```

I tried using this like:

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache('catalog_product_1234');
```

But it doesn't work. How can we clear the FPC just for one specific product?

Comment: Can we assume you are talking about EE FPC?

Comment: Oops. It's regarding Magento Enterprise FPC

Answer (score 0):

if you look into `Mage_PageCache_Model_Observer_Index`

```
protected function _cleanEntityCache(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $entity, array $ids)
        {
            $cacheTags = array();
            foreach ($ids as $entityId) {
                $entity->setId($entityId);
                $cacheTags = array_merge($cacheTags, $entity->getCacheIdTags());
            }
            if (!empty($cacheTags)) {
                Mage_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->clean($cacheTags);
            }
        }
```

So it looks you should do something like:

```
 $cacheTags = $product->getCacheIdTags();
 Mage_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->clean($cacheTags);
```